# How to simplify setting values to views in android widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, coding-style, android-widget

I'd like to ask if it's possible and how to simplify following code:

```
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.contact01Button, data.get(0).getFriendImage());
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.contact02Button, data.get(1).getFriendImage());
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.contact03Button, data.get(2).getFriendImage());
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.contact04Button, data.get(3).getFriendImage());
```

How to generate view id e.g. R.id.contactXXButton in a cycle or with something similar? I need to set many buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  String identifier = "contact" + String.format("%02s", i+1) + "Button";

  // next line taken from louiscoquio's answers. Credits go to him!
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier(identifier, "drawable", theContext.getPackageName());

  views.setImageViewBitmap(id, data.get(i).getFriendImage());
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works too:
int k = 0;
   for (int j = R.id.contact01Button; j <= R.id.contact07Button; ++j) {
    views.setImageViewBitmap(j, data.get(k).getFriendImage());
    k++;
   }

Comment: But then you rely on the assumption, that your button ids have the values 0..max and are ordered correctly. There's a good chance that it fails one day. Use the names and look up the values, it's safer.

Comment: yeah I got that. I'm using your solution because mine is too hardcoded. btw thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("contact0" + i + "Button", "drawable", getPackageName());
  views.setImageViewBitmap(drawableResourceId, data.get(i).getFriendImage());
}
```

It's pseudo-code, but it should be something like that.

See [Resources.getIdentifier() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.
Here is a simple demo for implementing findViewById() in loop.

```
for(int a=0; a<arr.length; a++) {
    String buttonID = "contact" + a + "Button";
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "com.package.your_app");   

    // To fetch Package name, you can directly call getPackageName() instead of static string "com.package.your_app

    buttons[a] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
}
```

Comment: button ids are 1-based and two digits. just concatenating `a` won't help for this special case

Comment: Yes you are right about to use `String.format("%02s", i+1)` but i have left that part for the user :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).